# Iframe height issue

Tags: iframe, height

I have an iframe loaded with dynamic datas. The page doesn't contains a postback. While deleting datas from this page its heights are not decreasing.

Why is it so?

Answer (score 1):

Because the page is net being rendered again. Use JavaScript to decrease the height after data is removed.

Something like (untested):

```
parent.window.document.getElementById("<FRAME_NAME>").height = parent.window.document.getElementById("<FRAME_NAME>").height - 30;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you mean that if you removed data from Iframe, the Iframe is not dynamically resizing it self to fit to content inside like span or div tags (if div size was not set).
if that so. sorry Iframe doesn't work like this.
it is inner page and its size is fixed and you must use Javascript  if you want to give dynamic resizing.

that's how I understood it. clarify me if I miss understood